# Pylons, cookies not being destroyed

Tags: python, cookies, pylons, session-cookies

I am trying to remove a cookie called "session" to logout a user.

```
request.cookies.pop('session', None)
response.set_cookie('session', '', max_age=-100, domain='.example.org')
response.set_cookie('session', '', max_age=-100, domain='www.example.org')
response.delete_cookie('session', '', domain='.example.org')
response.delete_cookie('session', '', domain='www.example.org')
```

As you can see, I am literally trying everything right now.

Nothing seems to erase the cookie.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using to store the cookies? `cookielib.CookieJar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pylons' built-in [sessions with Beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/modules/session.html), it is much simpler to use session.invalidate() and session.delete().

Are you using Beaker, or are you rolling your own solution for this ?